# Can't send postfix for evaluation to class

Tags: java, stack

I have been working a program for a long time and am stuck.  The program has a file with infix values in the file.  It reads the file and converts the infix to postfix then a class takes the postfix value and evaluates it.  I have converted to postfix but can’t send the string for evaluation in the other class.  I am using my own stack for this.  I must be doing something wrong.  I hope someone here can help me with this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("infix.txt"));


    InfixToPostfix infix = new InfixToPostfix(pw);
    EvalPostfix evpostfix = new EvalPostfix(pw);


    while(fileScan.hasNext()) {
        String stringinfix = fileScan.nextLine();


        infix.convertToPostfix(stringinfix);

            //CAN'T PASS POSTFIX STRING FROM INFIXTOPOSTFIX CLASS OVER TO EVALPOSTFIX CLASS
    //evpostfix.convertToPostfix(postfix);


    }
    fileScan.close();

    pw.close();
}
}


public class InfixToPostfix {

// Constructor:   
private PrintWriter pw;
ObjectStack operatorStack = new ObjectStack();
String stringinfix;
StringBuffer postfix;

public InfixToPostfix(PrintWriter pw) {
    this.pw = pw;
}

// Method to convert infix to postfix:
public String convertToPostfix(String stringinfix) {
       System.out.print("infix: " + stringinfix + "\n");
       pw.println("Infix: " + stringinfix);
      // Return a postfix representation of the expression in infix.

    char c;       // the first character of a token

     StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(stringinfix,"+-*/^() ",true);
                   // StringTokenizer for the input string

     //StringBuffer postfix = new StringBuffer(stringinfix.length());  // result
     postfix = new StringBuffer(stringinfix.length());
     // Process the tokens.
        while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {     

           String token = parser.nextToken();          // get the next token
           c = token.charAt(0);         // the first character of this token

           if ((token.length() == 1) && isOperator(c)) {    // if token is
                                                             //  an operator

              while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() &&
                  !lowerPrecedence(((String)operatorStack.top()).charAt(0), c)) {
                 // (Operator on the stack does not have lower precedence, so
                 //  it goes before this one.)

                 postfix.append(" ").append((String)operatorStack.pop());
              }

              if (c==')') {
                 // Output the remaining operators in the parenthesized part.
                    String operator = (String)operatorStack.pop();
                    while (operator.charAt(0)!='(') {
                       postfix.append(" ").append(operator);
                       operator = (String)operatorStack.pop();  
                    }
              }
              else
                 operatorStack.push(token); // Push this operator onto the stack.

           }
           else if ( (token.length() == 1) && isSpace(c) ) {    // else if
                                                        // token was a space
             ;                                                  // ignore it
           }
           else {  // (it is an operand)
             postfix.append(" ").append(token);  // output the operand
           }//end if

         }// end while for tokens

     // Output the remaining operators on the stack.
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
           postfix.append(" ").append((String)operatorStack.pop());
        }

     // Return the result.

        System.out.println("Postfix: " + postfix + "\n");

        pw.println("Postfix: " + postfix);

        return postfix.toString();
   } //end convertToPostfix


// Private methods:

   private boolean isOperator(char c) { // Tell whether c is an operator.

     return c == '+'  ||  c == '-'  ||  c == '*'  ||  c == '/'  ||  c == '^'
           || c=='(' || c==')';

   } //end isOperator

   private boolean isSpace(char c) {  // Tell whether c is a space.

     return (c == ' ');

   } //end isSpace


   private boolean lowerPrecedence(char op1, char op2) {

      switch (op1) {

         case '+':
         case '-':
            return !(op2=='+' || op2=='-') ;

         case '*':
         case '/':
            return op2=='^' || op2=='(';

         case '^':
            return op2=='(';

         case '(': return true;

         default:  // (shouldn't happen)
            return false;
      }

   } // end lowerPrecedence
 } //end class InfixToPostfix

 public class EvalPostfix {

private PrintWriter pw;

public EvalPostfix(PrintWriter pw) {
    this.pw = pw;
}


public void Evaluate(String postfix) {

    ObjectStack operatorStack = new ObjectStack();
    ObjectStack values = new ObjectStack();

    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {

        char c = postfix.charAt(i);
        System.out.println("String: " + c);

            if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                values.push(c);
            } else {
                    System.out.println("Inside evalpostfix else");
                    number1 = (int) values.pop();
                    number2 = (int) values.pop();
                    char op = (Character)operatorStack.pop();
                    switch (op) {
                        case '+':
                            values.push(number1 + number2);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            values.push(number1 - number2);
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            values.push(number1 * number2);
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            values.push(number1 / number2);
                            break;
                        case '^':
                            values.push(Math.pow(number1, number2));
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid operator order!");
                    }
            }
            int result = (int) values.pop();    
            System.out.println(result);
            pw.println("Evaluation: " + result);
            //return (Interger)values.pop();
        }

    //Object result = values.pop(); 
    //System.out.println(result);
    //pw.println("Evaluation: " + result);
    //return (Interger)values.pop();
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you use your own stack?

Comment: Pass Fish instance to `add()` not `String`

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying Jigar.